# Data Normalization with tensorflow tf-transform

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-transform

I'm doing a neural network prediction with my own datasets using Tensorflow. The first I did was a model that works with a small dataset in my computer. After this, I changed the code a little bit in order to use Google Cloud ML-Engine with bigger datasets to realize in ML-Engine the train and the predictions.

I am normalizing the features in the panda dataframe but this introduces skew and I get poor prediction results.

What I would really like is use the library `tf-transform` to normalize the data in the graph. To do this, I would like to create a function `preprocessing_fn`  and use the '`tft.scale_to_0_1`'. https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/getting_started.md

The main problem that I found is when I'm trying to do the predict. I'm looking for internet but I don't find any example of exported model where the data is normalized in the training. In all the examples I found, the data is NOT normalized anywhere.

What I would like to know is **If I normalize the data in the training and I send a new instance with new data to do the prediction, how is normalized this data?**

¿Maybe in the Tensorflow Data Pipeline? The variables to do the normalization are saved in some place?

In summary:  I'm looking for a way to normalize the inputs for my model and then that the new instances also become standardized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you don't really need tf.transform for this. All you need to do is to write a function that you call from both the training/eval input_fn and from your serving input_fn.

For example, assuming that you've used Pandas on your whole dataset to figure out the min and max

```
def add_engineered(features):
  min_x = 22
  max_x = 43
  features['x'] = (features['x'] - min_x) / (max_x - min_x)
  return features
```

Then, in your input_fn, wrap the features you return with a call to add_engineered:

```
def input_fn():
  features = ...
  label = ...
  return add_engineered(features), label
```

and in your serving_input fn, make sure to similarly wrap the returned features (NOT the feature_placeholders) with a call to add_engineered:

```
def serving_input_fn():
    feature_placeholders = ...
    features = feature_placeholders.copy()
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
         add_engineered(features), feature_placeholders)
```

Now, your JSON input at prediction time would only need to contain the original, unscaled values.

Here's a complete working example of this approach.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/feateng/taxifare/trainer/model.py#L130

tf.transform provides for a two-phase process: an analysis step to compute the min, max and a graph-modification step to insert the scaling for you into your TensorFlow graph.  So, to use tf.transform, you first need to write a Dataflow pipeline does the analysis and then plug in calls to tf.scale_0_to_1 inside your TensorFlow code.  Here's an example of doing this:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/criteo_tft

The add_engineered() approach is simpler and is what I would suggest.  The tf.transform approach is needed if your data distributions will shift over time, and so you want to automate the entire pipeline (e.g. for continuous training).

Comment: Sorry to answer so late, but the add_engineered() approach worked perfectly!

Comment: @lak I just came across this post as I had a similar question. If you have a moment, does this work with `tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver` ?

Comment: @Lak I also have a similar problem, I can't make it work. How can I use a simple python function that process a string feature/column, in a serving_input_fn with ServingInputReceiver? InputFnOps seems deprecated, can you point us to some example?

Comment: I've edited my answer above to use ServingInputReceiver instead.  Note that add_engineered() has to use TensorFlow operations (since it is part of a TensorFlow graph; you can not use arbitrary python functions like calling out to a database etc.)